# Conditional Filtering in Generator with random integer

Tags: python, loops, generator

I would like to create a generator of random numbers.

```
import numpy as np

rd_list = (np.random.randint(10) for i in range(6))
```

When I try with this I get values [7, 1, 4, 2, 0, 6].

I would like to filter these results by this condition < 5.

How can I get this result?

Comment: Can you please update the question to be more specific?  I can think of  many ways to approach this.  Please clarify the requirements.

Comment: Do you want to get 6 random numbers from 3 to 10?

Comment: I want to create a list of random numbers but only if each number satisfies a condition.

Comment: `np.random.randint(0, 5, 6)` will generate 6 numbers from `[0, 5)`

Comment: You have a source of 6 numbers. Do you want 6 numbers that match your condition, or do you just want to filter smaller numbers from the six?

Comment: I understand, but I don't want always to get 6 numbers. I want to filter inside the generator by a condition,

Comment: I want to filter smaller numbers from the six

Comment: Pass the conditional value as an argument into a function which generates the numbers.

Comment: This question is not clear. If you want to generate random numbers below `5` then why are you passing `10` to `randint`? If your question is how to filter a list of numbers then this has nothing to do with random numbers.

Comment: How can I pass the conditional value as argument into the function?

Comment: ok, so something like `my_gen = (value for value in np.random.randint(0, 10, 6) if my_func(value) < 5)` ?

Comment: @DeepSpace If I pass 5 in randint I always get 6 random number under 5. I want to get 6 random number between 0 and 9 and then filter the results > 5 out.

Comment: @AndrejKesely I get an error with your code

Comment: What is the point of filtering?  Just generate the random integers ‘correctly’ (as desired) in the first place.  (?)

Comment: @S3DEV If I generate a random integer with np.random.randint(5) I always get a list with 6 elements. If I filter random numbers out. I get always lists of different length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way using assignment expression (Python 3.8+):

```
import random 
nums = (n for _ in range(6) if (n := random.randint(0, 10)) < 5)
```

Thanks to Andrej's comment: Since you are already using `numpy`, you don't need the loop:

```
import numpy as np

nums = (n for n in np.random.randint(0, 10, 6) if n < 5)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for i in range(6):
    a = np.random.randint(10)
    if a < 5:
        List.append(a)
```

Comment: I would like to do it with a generator